# Fetch Http Response NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to execute a AWS Lambda in NodeJS (newbie to nodeJs) in which I make a http request. At the end of Lambda execution,  I wish to return response code and response message of http request.

Making the http request call:

```
var executeRequest = function(request, callback) {

const req = https.request(request, (res) => {

  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
     process.stdout.write(d);
  });
  callback(res);
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end(request.body);

};
```

Lambda Code:

```
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Formulate request 

    var result = executeRequest(request, function(response) {
         console.log("Response Code: ", response.statusCode);
         console.log("Response Message: ", response.statusMessage);
         // Successfully able to print the response above

        return response;
     });
     console.log("Result Response Code: ", result);
     console.log("Result Response Message: ", result);
     }
```

I wish to return the response.statusCode and response.statusMessage as response from Lambda

```
return{
    statusCode: <the code>,
    body: <the message>,
};
```

However, the result is populated as undefined. How to extract the required response parameter so they can be returned correctly?

** Edit: **
Snippet after changes suggested:
  Code using Promise:

```
var executeRequest = function(request, callback) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.request(request, function(res) {
            if(res.statusCode==200 || res.statusCode==404) {
                resolve(res);
            }
            else {
                console.error(res);
                reject(res.statusCode);
            }
        }).end(request.body || '');
    });
};


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Formulate request 

    var value = executeRequest(request).then(function(result) {
  console.log("Result ", result);
  const response = { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!') }; 
  return response;
 });

    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you post what is the current result you get ?

Comment: @ Kannaiyan : `Result Response Code:  undefined
 Result Response Message:  undefined`

Comment: might be easier with npm package `request`.

Comment: Move your console.log lines inside the "result" function, otherwise they will always be undefined (place them before `return response`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
exports.handler = function( event, context, callback ) { 
 //this is to allow function to return as soon as result is shown
 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
 var request = ...//I expect request is a predefined value or define the request here.

 executeRequest(request).then( function( result ) { 


  //keep all console log before return.
  console.log("Result ", result);

  const response = { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!') }; 

  callback(null, response);
  return;
 });
}
function executeRequest(request){
   return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

    https.request(request, function(res) {

     if(res.statusCode==200 || res.statusCode==404) {
        resolve(res);
     }else {
        console.error(res);
        reject(res.statusCode);
        return;
     }
    }).end(request.body || '');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that your `executeRequest` is asynchronous and your lambda doesn't know about that so it will simply return right away.

Instead of returning the response, pass it to `callback` as the second argument (first is error object)

```
callback(null, response)
```

This part is executed and without waiting for the `executeRequest` response, the rest of the code is executed

```
var result = executeRequest(request, function(response) {
     console.log("Response Code: ", response.statusCode);
     console.log("Response Message: ", response.statusMessage);
     // Successfully able to print the response above

    return response;
 });
```

So at this point

```
console.log("Result Response Code: ", result);
console.log("Result Response Message: ", result);
```

The `result` is still empty.

So you should instead do something like this.

```
var result = executeRequest(request, function(response) {
     console.log("Response Code: ", response.statusCode);
     console.log("Response Message: ", response.statusMessage);
     // Successfully able to print the response above

     callback(null, response);
 });
```

Comment: Getting response: ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Comment: You need to place the above code into the `exports.handler` body where the `callback` is defined, I will update the code snippet

Comment: Probably miinterpretating your comment.  :(   ... I have edited my question to include code based on suggested answer along with log statement being printed.

Comment: Asynchronous is the issue. Try using promises.

Comment: @Hans-Eric Lippke: Do you have code snippet I can reference? I have edited the question section to include using Promises. I however get `INFO Promise { <pending> }` in the logs

Comment: @learningMyWayThru Sure. I have posted an answer/example. Hopefully that should get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Lambda code to the following,

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Formulate request 

    var result = executeRequest(request, function(response) {
         console.log("Response Code: ", response.statusCode);
         console.log("Response Message: ", response.statusMessage);
         // Successfully able to print the response above

        callback(null, response);
     });

     }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Getting error: ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Comment: You might have typed it, instead of copy paste. You can see it is defined with the arrow function.

Comment: @Kanniyan: Probably miinterpretating your comment.  :(   ... I have edited my question to include code based on suggested answer along with log statement being printed.

Comment: console.log("Test response1: ", result);
    console.log("Test response2: ", callback);  Since the function is not a synchronous call. You cannot print the variable outside of the function. You can try to use async and await.